# How to completely remove node from Ubuntu 18.04.3 without root?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, node-modules, ubuntu-18.04

I have nodejs installed in my pc and found different versions with and without root access.

**Without root access**

```
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ node -v
v10.12.0
```

**With root access**

```
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo node -v
sudo: node: command not found
```

**I removed node with root access.**

```
sudo apt-get remove node
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package node
```

But when trying to remove the node package without root access, the following error comes.

```
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ apt-get remove npm
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: apt-get is a high privileged command which itself requires Sudo (higher privilege) to run. It's not only for node but for any other application you need to install or remove. Please check apt documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to remove the node and npm using

```
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ which node
/home/allen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/node
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ rm -rf /home/allen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/node
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ which npm
/home/allen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/npm
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ rm -rf /home/allen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/npm
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ node -v
bash: /home/allen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/node: No such file or directory
allen@allen-HP-Notebook:~$ npm -v
bash: /home/allen/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```